# '.' or '->' C struct accessor

Tags: c, struct, operators, accessor

What is the difference between `.` and `->` when accessing data in a C structure? I couldn't find any difference in my several attempts. Both provide me access to the desired data.

Comment: -> use when you try to call smt from pointer to struct
. when you create object and call

Comment: If you can't find any difference, try replacing one with the other without changing anything else, and see if your program still compiles :-)

Comment: There is literally no code where those two things have no difference. One will always fail to compile

Comment: What does your data look like? What does your struct look like? Could you give a minimal example?

Comment: What does the text book tell about these operators?

Answer (score 6):

The `->` operator is only syntactical sugar:

```
x->y
```

is the same as

```
(*x).y
```

The parentheses are necessary due to the `.` operator having higher precedence than the `*` operator.

Answer (score 5):

`.` is used with structs. `->` is used with pointers (to structs).

Answer (score 2):

> 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 The first operand of the . operator shall have an atomic, qualified,
>   or unqualified structure or union type, and the second operand shall
>   name a member of that type.
>
> 2 The first operand of the -> operator shall have type ‘‘pointer to
>   atomic, qualified, or unqualified structure’’ or ‘‘pointer to atomic,
>   qualified, or unqualified union’’, and the second operand shall name a
>   member of the type pointed to.
>
> Semantics
>
> 3 A postfix expression followed by the . operator and an identifier
>   designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that
>   of the named member,95) and is an lvalue if the first expression is an
>   lvalue. If the first expression has qualified type, the result has the
>   so-qualified version of the type of the designated member.
>
> 4 A postfix expression followed by the -> operator and an identifier
>   designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that
>   of the named member of the object to which the first expression
>   points, and is an lvalue.96) If the first expression is a pointer to a
>   qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of
>   the designated member.

Answer (score 1):

Underneath is a piece of example code to showcase the difference:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
}              // one single struct wit a member called 'a'

MyStruct *st;  // pointer to struct
st->a = 10;    // access member via '->' operator

MyStruct st2;  // struct variable
st2.a = 10;    // access member via '.' operator
```

You can see that both usages are similar, but the difference is in the type of the `st` or `st2` variables. Your choice for the type of the variable determines which operator you must use.

Comment: Side note: `st->a = 10;` immediately after `MyStruct *st;` is a fatal mistake as `st` has not been pointed at a `MyStruct` or sufficient storage for a `MyStruct`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between `->` operator and plain `structs / unions` or any other type, other than pointers to `structs / unions`. The `->` is accessing a member in `struct / union` pointed by your pointer. Meaning, after creating a `struct / union` with members, the `struct / union` members can be accessed either by `.` if holding the `struct / union` itself or by `->` if holding the `pointer` to the `struct / union`

An Example:

```
// creating one instance of struct s, and a pointer to an instance of struct s. struct s is a struct holding one int called 'data'.

struct s{int data;}struct_s_instance, *struct_s_instance_pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
struct_s_instance.data = 3;           // access using the '.' operator 
struct_s_instance_pointer->data = 4;  // pointer access using the '->' operator 
printf("%d-%d", struct_s_instance.data, struct_s_instance_pointer->data);
```

You can't access `data` in `struct_s_instance_pointer` using the `.` (i.e. `struct_s_instance_pointer.data`) or access `data` in `struct_s_instance` using `->` (i.e. `struct_s_instance->data`). These are totaly different things.

Note that when given a pointer, such as `struct_s_instance_pointer` you can derefernce it: `*struct_s_instance_pointer`  and then the operator `.` can and should be used: `(*struct_s_instance_pointer).data`

Comment: "*There is no connection between -> operator and structs, unions*" -- sure there is

Comment: @FelixPalmen how can you access data in a struct (not a pointer) using -_>_?

Comment: How can you access an object that *isn't* a struct or union member using `->`?

Comment: I guess I'm missing something but -> is used only for pointers. Meaning, no usage for structs, unions (and also ints, chars and such). Am I wrong?

Comment: `->` is shorthand for dereference and member access. So sure it requires a pointer. It *also* requires the pointer to point to either a `struct` or a `union`, because only in structs and unions, you can access *members*.

Comment: You are totally right. I meant they have no connection to plain structs or unions without pointers. I will edit